# JQuery animate() on mousewheel bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. This works perfectly fine:

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            //scroll down
            //console.log('Down');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").css({"height": "90px"});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").css({"margin": "15px auto"});
        } else {
            //scroll up
            //console.log('Up');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").css({"height": "140px"});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").css({"margin": "45px auto"});
        }
    });
```

However, when I change .css to .animate, it will only work when scrolling down but the object won't animate when scrolling back up again.

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            //scroll down
            //console.log('Down');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").animate({height:'90px'});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").animate({margin:'15px auto'});
        } else {
            //scroll up
            //console.log('Up');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").animate({height:'140px'});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").animate({margin:'45px auto'});
        }
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I guess the problem is obvious but I just can't see it.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stop();` to break one animation and switch to the other

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            //scroll down
            //console.log('Down');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").stop().animate({height:'90px'});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").stop().animate({margin:'15px auto'});
        } else {
            //scroll up
            //console.log('Up');
            $(".spacer_top_panel").stop().animate({height:'140px'});
            $(".spacer_top_panel nav").stop().animate({margin:'45px auto'});
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, not needed for animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The animation actually works for scrolling back up but it just takes some time until it kicks off.